# Dynamically assign value to deeply nested list

Tags: r, list, recursion, dynamic, reflection

I have a vector of strings, like

```
> cc <- c("a", "b", "c")
> cc
[1] "a" "b" "c"
```

...and I have a list with a structure like:

```
> ll <- list("a" = list("b" = list("c" = "hola")))
> ll
$a
$a$b
$a$b$c
[1] "hola"
```

What's the easiest way to dynamically access the elements of `ll` using `cc` so that I can reassign the values of the list without building a new list? Basically, I want access to the *reference* `ll$a$b$c`, not it's value.

Hard-coding this, we would use syntax like:

```r
ll[[cc[1]]][[cc[2]]][[cc[3]]] <- ... # or
ll[["a"]][["b"]][["c"]] <- ... # or
ll$a$b$c <- ...
```

...which makes me think I want an `apply` or `lapply`, but it's not simply `lapply(cc, ...)`, because that doesn't recursively apply the selection on `ll`. It would instead do something like:

```r
ll[c[1]] <- ...
ll[c[2]] <- ...
ll[c[3]] <- ...
```

So I thought I'd need to use `Reduce()`. Because, essentially, what I'm trying to do is apply a function to a variable then apply a function to the result, then apply a function to the result, etc:

```
temp <-   ll[[c[1]]]
temp <- temp[[c[2]]]
temp <- temp[[c[3]]]
...
```

But I'm not sure this would work either, because we're not saving a reference to `ll[[c[1]]]` in `temp`, we're saving its value (the second line should throw an error).

I get the feeling that the solution will involve `Reduce`, calling the list access function as `` `[[` `` and maybe a `do.call()`, but I'm lost. Any ideas?

Comment: Subsetting is easy: `Reduce(function(l, i) l[[i]], cc, init = ll)`. Subset-assignment is the issue here, because it combines two recursions (going down to find the element and then up-again for the assignment).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use:

```
ll[[cc]]
#[1] "hola"
```

This is not a well known usage of the base `[[` operator, but it's precisely what you are after, it seems to me.

From `?"[["`, "Recursive (list-like) objects" section:

> ‘[[’ can be applied recursively to lists, so that if the single
>        index ‘i’ is a vector of length ‘p’, ‘alist[[i]]’ is equivalent to
>        ‘alist[[i1]]...[[ip]]’ providing all but the final indexing
>        results in a list.

Of course you can use it also to reassign the value:

```
ll[[cc]] <- "hello"
ll
#$a
#$a$b
#$a$b$c
#[1] "hello"
```

Comment: Wow, that's clean! Thanks!